# laravel on-demand notification passing email array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

Given several filters, I want to pass an array of emails and names from the `User.php` model to an on-demand notification.

Unfortunately, inside the User.php model I got this appends:

```php
    /**
     * The accessors to append to the model's array form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $appends = [
        'profile_photo_url', 
    ];
```

which cancels all the helpers `Arr::except()`, `Arr::only()` ... all of them are useless to get rid of the `profile_photo_url`. Ok, i got rid of it  by commenting it out.

So, I try to get the email and name columns from the User like so:

**ScheduleClass.php**

```php
$users_ec_ = User::where('area_id',$area_value_especial->id)->get(['email','name'])->toArray();
```

when I `dd($users_ec_)` I get:

```
      [
        0 => array:1 [
            "email@mail.mx" => "JUán perez"
        ]
```

When I try to call the notification:

```php
     Notification::route('mail',$users_ec_)
           ->notify(new Signed($eventos_ec));
            ;
```

**Signed.php**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use App\Models\Meeting;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

class Firmadas extends Notification implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable;

    private $meetings;
 
    public function __construct(Collection $meetings)
    {
        $this->meetings = $meetings;
    }


    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }


    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        $meetings = $this->meetings;
        return (new MailMessage)
            ->subject('New signatures...')
            ->markdown('emails.signed',compact('meetings'))
            ;
    }
}
```

I get the following error, as for the users array:

> [2022-09-28 09:23:44] local.ERROR: Attempt to read property "email" on array {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Attempt to read property "email" on array at /home/vagrant/myProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Notifications/Channels/MailChannel.php:228)
> [stacktrace]

What am I missing? How do I solve it?

## Solved

According to [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/notifications#on-demand-notifications):

> "provide an array that contains the email address as the key and the name as the value of the first element in the array"

**ScheduleClass.php**

```php
$users_ec_ = User::where('area_id',$area_e_c->id)->get(['email','name'])->toArray();
 //given that in User.php Model there's this "protected $appends" profile_photo_url, I had to set my own foreach to get rid of the `profile_photo_url` key, because that `protected $appends` cancels out all the Array Laravel helpers, such as Arr::except Arr::only ... etc
      $users_ec=[];
      foreach ($users_ec_ as $user){
          $users_ec[$user['email']] = $user['name'];//This is key according to the docs
       }
     //To finally pass the email and name array to the Notification::route method:
      Notification::route('mail',$users_ec)
         ->notify(new Signed($meetings_ec));
         ;
```

That did the trick

Comment: can you share the code of `Signed` class ? It might have a clue.

Comment: Done. But I think the array problem has more to do with the `Notification::route()` method, that is complaining about my array.

Answer (score 1):

Your user array is a nested array.

The Laravel documentation https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/notifications#on-demand-notifications

```
Notification::route('mail', [
    'barrett@example.com' => 'Barrett Blair',
])->notify(new InvoicePaid($invoice));
```

Try with $users_ec_[0] to see if it works.
Then you can always work your way around the toArray() by building the array yourself or looping through the entries to send notifications

Comment: You are right. [According to the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/notifications#on-demand-notifications): "`provide an array that contains the email address as the key and the name as the value of the first element in the array`" like so: `$users_ec[$user['email']] = $user['name'];` (I will add the details in the bottom of my question)

Comment: Great, that should do the trick